Problems with displaying git changes
When deleting one line, the git displays the entire file in red and green. In intellij idea itself, the changes are displayed correctly, and git diff shows that all lines have been deleted and re-added. My operating system is windows.
Global git settings:
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- $f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- $f
filter.1fs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.reguired=true
http.sslbackend=openss1
core.autocrif=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=true
pull. rebase=false
core. filemode=false

Project git settings:
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- $f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- $f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-proces
filter.1fs.required=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=true
pull.rebase=false
credential.helper=manager
init.defaultbranch=master
core.filemode=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true


"git diff shows that all lines have been deleted and re-added" End-of-line changes.

What happens if you add -w as option to the diff command you are using?
